# Permission denied when trying to write with FileWriter/BufferedWriter in java.

Tags: java, file, bufferedwriter

im really struggling one this one. Basically im working with a couple of my classmates to a project where we have to deliver a space wars remake and we implemented a single player mode where you can actually get scores. problem is i can read my file but cannot write on it. ive tryed with all the system i could find online but didn't manage to get the error solved. here is the code of the class that manages the highscore system. i even tryed creating the file with code and tryed deleting it and recreating an empty one. the file is in the home directory of the project right now. the metods readFile and getHighscores work but the check one always gets stuck in the writing part.
the error i get is " Il privilegio richiesto non appartiene al client
[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@6eb60ef7" 
which translates in "The requested privilege does not belong to the client"

Keep in mind it's all in a git repository where i should have all the permissions but it's basically the only idea left in my mind.

```
package controller;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

/**
 *the creation of the HighscoreManager class.
 */
public class HighscoreManager {

    private static final int LAST_HIGHSCORE_INDEX = 9;
    private static final String FILE_NAME = "/Highscores.txt";
    private ArrayList<Integer> highscores = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    /**
     * reads the file and loads the highscore list.
     */
    private void readFile() {
        InputStream is = null;
        InputStreamReader isr = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String s;
        highscores.clear();
        try {
            is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(FILE_NAME);
            isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
                highscores.add(Integer.parseInt(s));
            }
            if(br!=null && isr !=null && is!= null) {
                br.close();
                isr.close();
                is.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * checks if the passed score is an actual highscores.
     * @param score 
     */
    public void checkHighscores(final int score) {
        readFile();
        File file = new File(FILE_NAME);
        boolean newHighscoreFound = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < highscores.size(); i++) {
            if (score > highscores.get(i)) {
                newHighscoreFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (newHighscoreFound) {
            highscores.add(LAST_HIGHSCORE_INDEX, score);
            Collections.sort(highscores);
            Collections.reverse(highscores);
            for (int i : highscores) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
            if(!file.exists()) {
                try {
                    file.createNewFile();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            FileWriter fw = null;
            BufferedWriter bw = null;
            try {
                fw = new FileWriter(file);
                bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                for(int i : highscores) {
                    bw.write(i);
                }
            } catch(IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
            } finally {
                if(fw != null && bw != null) {
                    try {
                        fw.close();
                        bw.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
                    }

                }
            }

        }
    }

    /**
     * returns an array list of strings containing all the current highscores.
     * @return toBeReturned
     */
    public ArrayList<String> getHighscores() {
        ArrayList<String> toBeReturned = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            highscores.clear();
            readFile();
            for (int i : highscores) {
                toBeReturned.add(String.valueOf(i));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            System.out.println("There you have your highscores.");
        }
        return toBeReturned;
    }
}
```

Comment: The path points to /... in Linux it's the root dir in Windows this path does not exist (maybe C:/Highscores.txt), so use System.getProperty("user.dir"); and concat with FILE_NAME to get the current directory of the project Highscores.txt.

Comment: i don't know how it exactly works but i can assure you that if i use /Highscores.txt as path and keep the file in the git repository where i m programming i can read the file without any problem. the problem is all about permission being denied in writing. i can read the file without any given problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to access the `Class` object to load a file (or indeed the associated `ClassLoader`). Just use normal Java IO.

To read your set of high scores:

```
highScores = Files.lines(Paths.get(FILE_NAME))
                .map(Integer::parseInt)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

To write a new set of high scores:

```
Files.write(Paths.get(FILE_NAME), highScores.stream()
                .map(String::valueOf)
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

(Also, why is this tagged with "git"?)

Comment: i tagged it with git since i thought it might have been a problem related to the repository permission in git. I just recently started using it and wasn't sure if it was a limitation it could set up. i use the class object to load the file because our teacher told us that it's basically the only noneless the best way to work with files in the jar file. Don't know if it responds to truth but as a student i just trust what i m told most of the times

Comment: Depends what kind of file it is, but it is very rare to have to use `getResource()` on classes or classloaders for simple text files like the one you are using to keep your high scores.

Comment: Dunno i just followed the given instruction since im not really confident with files yet. may i ask you what it is that u posted above and how to use it?

Comment: See official docs: [Files.lines](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-) and [Files.write](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write-java.nio.file.Path-java.lang.Iterable-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-).The first statement returns a `Stream<String>` of all lines in the file, maps each of them to an integer and puts them in a list; the second turns the list into a `Stream<Integer>`, maps each value to a `String` and puts it back in a `List<String>`, which the `write` method takes as an argument.